# What is the proper way to run fetch calls which use reactive components from a store?

Tags: fetch-api, svelte, sveltekit

I am getting two reactive variables I need from a store to use for my fetch calls. I need these fetch calls to rerun when the data in these store values change. I am able to make this work however when I reload the page it causes my app to crash because there are no values that are getting from the store. I am able to make it work if I disable ssr on the +page.js file.

I also believe it is relevant to mention that I am using a relative URL (/api) to make the fetch call because I have a proxy server to bypass CORS

What is the proper way to get this data by rerunning the fetch calls using a reactive component from a store without disabling ssr? Or is this the best/only solution?

+page.svelte

```
<script>
    import { dateStore, shiftStore } from '../../../lib/store';
    
    $: shift = $shiftStore
    $: date = $dateStore
    
    /**
     * @type {any[]}
     */
     export let comments = []
    /**
     * @type {any[]}
     */
    let areas = []
    //console.log(date)
    
    
    async function getComments() {
        const response = await fetch(`/api/${date.toISOString().split('T')[0]}/${shift}/1`)
        comments = await response.json()
        console.log(comments)
    }
    
    async function getAreas() {
        const response = await fetch(`/api/api/TurnReportArea/1/${date.toISOString().split('T')[0]}/${shift}`)
        areas = await response.json()
        console.log(areas)
    }

    // both of these call function if date or shift value changes
    $: date && shift && getAreas()
    $: date , shift , getComments()
    
</script>
```

I tried to use the +page.js file for my fetch calls, however I cannot use the reactive values in the store in the +page.js file. Below the date variable is set as a 'Writble(Date)' When I try to add the $ in front of the value let dare = $dateStore, I get the error 'Cannot find name '$dateSrote'' If i put the $ in the fetch call I get the error 'Cannot find $date'. Even if I were able to make this work, I do not understand how my page would know to rerender if these fetch calls were ran so I do not think this is the solution. As I mentioned, the only solution I have found is to disable ssr on the +page.js, which I do not think is the best way to fix this issue.

```
import { dateStore, shiftStore } from "../../../lib/store"

export const load = async ({ }) => {
        let shift = shiftStore
        let date = dateStore
        const getComments = async() => {
        const commentRes = await fetch(`/api/${date.toISOString().split('T')[0]}/${shift}/1`)
        const comments = await commentRes.json()
        console.log(comments)
        }
        
        const getAreas = async () => {
        const areasRes = await fetch(`/api/api/TurnReportArea/1/${date.toISOString().split('T')[0]}/${shift}`)
        const areas = await areasRes.json()
        console.log(areas)
        }

        return {
                comments: getComments(),
                areas: getAreas()
        }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that the stores are actually the ones causing the issues, because in this [repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/8fcb1f0218af455f9f0a76b196785ee8?version=3.55.1), I did not run into any problems. Is there a particular reason why you have to wrap the store inside the `date` and `shift` variables?

Comment: I had to wrap them to make them reactive. If I try to reference them directly It does now work. 
dateStore && shiftStore && getAreas();
dateStore && shiftStore && getComments();

I think the issue is that the store is not loading on the refresh because I do have default values in the store and if I take out the reactive $: date statements at the bottom of the script and refresh without disabling SSR then my app does not crash. 
Also, as I mentioned disabling SSR does fix the issue, I just did not know if this was the best way to set up fetch calls with variables from a store.

Comment: I mean, in any environment, if you want to execute a function after a variable has been changed, this would be the best way to do it in svelte, and you don't really need to add the `$:` reactive variable since a svelte `store` will always update it's subscriber if any changes was made